# How to Create Context in Netty

Tags: java, http, netty

Good morning,

in java.sun version of http servers we used to do this for creating contexts and different handlers :

```
server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PORT), 0);
    server.createContext("/@@getPersonalImage", new PersonalImageHandler());
    server.createContext("/@@getProfile", new ProfileGetter());
```

and then you could reach it by typing

```
 127.0.0.1:15000/@@getProfile
```

but in the netty i think i have searched every thing in examples etc , but havent seen creating contexts like this , is this some sort of depcerated method or what ?

could you please help me to achieve this sort of context in the netty too ? thanks in advance

Comment: What is a Context equal to? Are Context just handlers for the traffic?

Comment: yes mate , like i mentioned the address 127.0.0.1:1500/@@getProfile should be passed to ProfileGetter() handler

Comment: The netty framework is not intended to be a full web application server on its own. If you want to have nice handler methods for different urls, think about switching to a framework that's made for that. You can certainly make it work, several such frameworks use netty under the hood, but they add lots of code on top that you'll need to write yourself when you go with pure netty.

Comment: may you please mention 1 and obviously best framework which uses netty :)

Comment: http://netty.io/wiki/adopters.html lists lots of products that build upon netty. You could have a look at http://blog.takipi.com/java-micro-frameworks-the-new-trend-you-cant-ignore/ or https://opensource.com/life/15/10/4-java-web-frameworks for frameworks (not sure if any of thoses uses netty though) edit: playframework does apparently http://jto.github.io/articles/play_anatomy_part1_bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty works in this fashion.

1. You have the server and/or client you must setup and when you set the server up you can add handlers by adding a ChannelInitializer. You can also add or remove on the fly, but this is not always recommended as it can be costly.
2. When you need to pass data to or from that is not network related or related to the network data you read you can take several approaches, such as extending the handlers and adding some sort of field where you can access or put data or use ChannelAttributes.

Their tutorials and examples definitely are helpful when building out. I will comment on their example and explain and hope that is helpful.

[From their User Guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html)
[Channels](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html)

Client Code

```
package io.netty.example.time;

public class TimeClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(); 
            b.group(workerGroup); 
            b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class); 
            b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); 
            b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {  //** This is the ChannelInitializer - The Channel is the nexus basically to communications, you add handlers to the channel in the order of how data is handled
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new TimeClientHandler()); //** Here we are adding TimeClient Handler to the SocketChannel  seen below, there are many ways to add handlers 
                }
            });

            // Start the client.
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync(); // (5)

            // Wait until the connection is closed.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Handler Code

```
package io.netty.example.time;

import java.util.Date;

public class TimeClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf m = (ByteBuf) msg; // Here we are getting the message
        try {
            long currentTimeMillis = (m.readUnsignedInt() - 2208988800L) * 1000L; //** We will always have to write the logic unless there is already a netty handler for it, but even then you may or probably will have to implement business logic handler specific to your application(s)
            System.out.println(new Date(currentTimeMillis));
            ctx.close();  //** you can close a connection on a channel or a ChannelHandlerContext
        } finally {
            m.release(); //** Here you have to release the buffer
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

So if you want to be able to reach out, when you construct the handler you can add your own fields. For the attributes method see ChannelHandler for examples [ChannelHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html)

EDIT: Will yes there is some Netty handlers for IP specific filtering, but I am not sure about it specifically. I am not sure what your trying to do as I do not know the other library you mentioned. To give you an Idea of how I use Netty may help you. I have a MMO style game, when a client connects its over TCP w/SSL when they connect though in the handler I have a Session class i create and tracks all there information. Then I prompt the client through my own network protocol to open another connection to the server using TCP w/o SSL. I add that to their Session, Then i negotiate if they can receive UDP and if so I build out a specific UDP handler for them and attach it to the Session. Each Session has its own Instance of the handlers in the Handler that allows me to read and write from one channel to another and or handle that person. Each session also references each of the handlers, channel and connection data. I also have a file server build on http and a post server built in netty, the client implements native Java, hence i used a web-server to not have initial dependencies.

Comment: so you mean in netty , you should manually create your own contexts inside the initChannel , depending on the request address , right?

Comment: To long to put here. See Edit.

Comment: so as i understoud netty is made for servers like openfire , not http , but you can use it as http for more concurrent connections :) thanks mate

Comment: You can use it for Http! I use it for all my file transfering and parameter posting [Their user guies/examples](http://netty.io/wiki/index.html)